# Make div's width fit content without css3 intrinsic sizing

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a div's width fit the content, all in one line, without intrinsic sizing?

I tried `width:auto`, but that is too small and the content is one word and then the next word wraps.

Comment: give us some code and tried of yourself. Width:auto; is used to reset a width already set earlier in CSS.Does white-space rings a bell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in your css `div { display:table; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
div {white-space:nowrap;}
```

will fix your wrapping